# What operations in JPA bypass Persistance context/Cache and directly invoke in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am referring **Pro JPA2** book for Learning JPA .and it says that queries ,bulk update and bulk delete bypass the persistence context and executed at database,Is it mean that these operation are not executed on persistence context and directly invoked in database. 
e.g. **find** method is executed on persistence context but select/update/delete query is executed on database . **find** may or may not hit the database but ***SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE*** will hit the database.
please provide me more insight here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it mean that these operation are not executed on persistence context and directly invoked in database

The [JPA 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) (see below the extract from it) does not state that the operations will not use persistence context. But rather the result of these operations will not be reflected for entities already in memory or cache.

> ### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> ...
>
> Bulk update maps directly to a database update operation, bypassing optimistic locking checks. Portable applications must manually update the value of the version column, if desired, and/or manually validate the value of the version column.
>
> The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the bulk update or delete.
>
> *Caution should be used when executing bulk update or delete operations because they may result in inconsistencies between the database and the entities in the active persistence context. In general, **bulk update and delete operations should only be performed within a transaction in a new persistence context or before fetching or accessing entities whose state might be affected by such operations.***

Comment: I need to dig into specs